# App Store link opens in Safari but not in Chrome

Tags: ios

I have an app store link..
When i open it in chrome on my phone it just opens up this apple page and doesn't redirect users to the App Store.

[image]

However, it works fine on Safari.

How do I get this to work properly on Chrome or other browsers?

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Might want to try here: https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/en-us

Answer (score 1):

I was having the exact same issue but when I refreshed Chrome it turned out I had a cached copy.  Once refreshed it asks to open in the App Store just fine.